# Is the definition of continuity in a topological space trivial?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Refer to Munkres, Topology on the definition of an open set:

> If $X$ is a topological space with topology $\mathcal{T}$ we say that a subset $U$ of $X$ is an $\textbf{open set}$ of $X$ if $U$ belongs to the collection $\mathcal{T}$.

And the definition of continuity:

> A function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is said to $\textbf{continuous}$ if for each open subset $V$ of $Y$, the set $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset of $X$.

If the above definitions are true, then if $f^{-1}(V)$ exists, it would imply a surjective map of $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ (since by open set definition of $V$, we know $V \subset Y)$, so “ the set $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset of $X$” is always true (even without continuity)? Clearly this does not make sense. Is there a way to resolve this?

My intuition might be that $f^{-1}$ might not necessarily exist within this context?

Comment: Why do you think that $f$ is surjective? The definition of inverse image is $f^{-1}(V) = \{x\in X: f(x)\in V\}$.

Comment: $f^{-1}(V)$ *always* exists (though it might be empty.  Don't confuse evaluation of the inverse function at a point with the preimage of a set.

Comment: You should not say "definitions are true". A definition is not a statement.

Comment: This is one (of several) situations where the meaning of the symbols depends on context.  If $f$ is the function that maps the plane to itself by rotating it $90^\circ$ about the origin and $A$ is a point on the horizontal axis, then $f(A)$ would represent a point on the vertical axis.  In this case, $f$ happens to be 1-1 and onto, so invertible, and we also have $f^{-1}(A)$ is another point on the vertical axis.  

However, if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is *any* function and $A \subseteq X$, then $f(A)$ is a subset of $Y$.  If $B \subseteq Y$, then $f^{-1}(B)$ is a subset (possibly empty) of $X$.

Comment: In an attempt to make things more clear, in **Real Analysis** Barry Simon uses square brackets instead of round brackets, , e.g. $f^{-1}[B]$ instead of $f^{-1}(B)$, when talking about images and preimages of sets. (See, for example, [page 5 Propn 1.2.2 (2)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Real_Analysis/7brzrQEACAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1).)  There $B\subseteq Y$, so he writes $f^{-1}[B] \subseteq X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the above definitions are true, then if $f^{-1}(V)$ exists, it would imply a surjective map of $f$ from $X$ to $Y$

No it wouldn't. Consider, say, the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x, & x \in (0,1) \\ -1 , & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$Take $V = (0,1)$ (so $f^{-1}(V) = V$). Certainly open under the usual topology, but I don't think we would be saying that $f$ is a surjection.

My guess is you're unintentionally conflating notions of $f^{-1}(x)$ as representing the inverse to the function $f$ at the point $y$, and the notion $f^{-1}(V)$, the preimage of the set $V$, defined by
$$
f^{-1}(V) := \{ x \in \operatorname{domain}(f) \mid f(x) \in V \}
$$
For non-surjective mappings, we may not always be able to have a well-defined *inverse function* (for instance, for the map above, since $f(-2) = f(2) = -1$), but the *preimage set* should always be well-defined for any function. For instance, for the function above, $f^{-1}((0,1)) = (0,1)$ and $f^{-1}(\{-1\}) = \mathbb{R} \setminus (0,1)$.

Of additional note: we can see that the function $f$ given previously is not continuous, since $(-\frac 3 2, -\frac 1 2)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ but $f^{-1}((-\frac 3 2, -\frac 1 2)) = (-\infty,0] \cup [1,\infty)$ which is not open.

Answer (score 1):

For a function $f : X \to Y$, $f^{-1}$ is defined on subsets $A \subseteq Y$ by $f^{-1}(A) = \{x \in X : f(x) \in A\}$. This always exists as a subset of $X$. As an exercise, you can try to prove that $f^{-1}(Y) = X$.

This contrasts with the definition of $f^{-1}$ on *elements* of $Y$, since there isn't always an element of $X$ that maps to a given element of $Y$.